# nginx proxy_read_timeout behaviour

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, nginx, postman

I am uploading a document as a MultipartFile upload via a rest api. There is a nginx reverse proxy in front the application server which has **proxy_read_timeout as 60s**.

But a request which takes over 2m 7s got success. Bases on proxy_read_timeout should not I except to get a time out for any request where response time gets over 60s?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Read the [docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout) carefully:

> The timeout is set only between two successive read operations, not for the transmission of the whole response. If the proxied server does not transmit anything within this time, the connection is closed.

So any acknowledge for the received packet of data from the upstream will reset the `proxy_read_timeout` timer.

Comment: could you please explain how the proxy_read_timeout  is getting reset?

Comment: There is a _window size_ for every established TCP connection (see TCP [flow control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Flow_control) or [TCP window scale option](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_window_scale_option) article for the details). After every portion of data with the length determined by TCP window size the receiving side should send an ACK packet (acknowledge). Receiving that ACK packet from your java backend makes `proxy_read_timeout` timer reset.